# why 'if not' is not applying in multiple 'or' statement

Tags: delphi

The code goes like this :

```pascal
procedure TForm1.dxBarButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not (dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Johnny') or (dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Stephen') then begin
    ShowMessage('Not for you.');
    abort;
  end else begin
    Form8 :=TForm8.Create(nil);
    try
      Form8.ShowModal;
    finally
      Form8.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

However, when the text displayed is 'Stephen' I still get the message 'Not for you.' ??
Why is the code not differentiating?

Comment: It seems like you are using the auto-created `Form8` global variable to store a new `TForm8` instance, and then you leave a dangling pointer. That's bad. Use a local variable instead.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Only if the the auto-creation of Form8 hasn't been turned off... But otherwise you're right - you should not use the auto-defined Form8 instance variable in this manner, but a local variable instead.

Comment: @HeartWare: Actually, my comment is accurate regardless of this setting. Even if this setting is off, the global variable is still there (especially if the OP's code compiles!), so you are in fact using a global variable and leaving a dangling pointer behind you. But of course the consequences are far worse if this variable is actually used to point to the auto-created form. I suppose that's your point, and that is very true indeed.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Only if the form is auto-created can you store a "new" TForm8 instance :-) So your comment is only valid (syntactically) in the case of auto-creation being enabled. Otherwise it wouldn't be a "new" instance :-) But we're splitting hairs now :-)

Comment: Just like you can't (syntactically) ask "Do you want another cup of coffee" if the person hasn't already had (at least) one :-)

Comment: @HeartWare: So it is not possible for me to buy a new car if I have never owned a car before? (Soon we need to migrate this discussion to English language SE!)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Depends on your understanding of "new" in the specific context. If  "new" is understood as "one that replaces a previous one", then no. If "new" is understood as "opposite of old" or "just created", then yes. I understand it as the first :-). But otherwise you're right about EL SE :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
if not (dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Johnny') or (dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Stephen') then
```

the `if .. then` is part of the [conditional](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#If_Statements) statement. The condition is

```
not (dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Johnny') or (dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Stephen')
```

which is an expression. Now, according to the Pascal [rules of operator precedence](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operator_Precedence), `not` has higher precedence than `or`, so the expression is parsed like this:

```
(not (dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Johnny'))
  or
(dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Stephen')
```

which is equivalent to

```
(dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text <> 'Johnny')
  or
(dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Stephen')
```

That is, the statement is `True` [iff](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iff) at least one of the following statements are true:

1. The text isn't `'Johnny'`
2. The text is `'Stephen'`.

Hence, if the text is `'Johnny'`, both statements are false and the expression evaluates to `False`. On the other hand, if the text is not `'Johnny'`, the first statement is `True` and so the entire [disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) is `True`.

In other words, the expression can be written simply

```
dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text <> 'Johnny'.
```

A simpler way to realise this: if the first disjunct is `False` (that is, if the name *is* `'Johnny'`), then clearly the second disjunct is `False` and so can be omitted.

What you want is

```
not
(
  (dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Johnny')
    or
  (dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Stephen')
)
```

which, according to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), can be written

```
not (dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Johnny')
  and
not (dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text = 'Stephen')
```

(recalling that `not` has higher precedence than `and`) or, equivalently,

```
(dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text <> 'Johnny')
  and
(dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text <> 'Stephen')
```

Comment: Why is OP using round brackets twice but not the `not` also twice? I tell beginners always: just like you can overrule [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) in mathematics thru round brackets you should in doubt put just more round brackets into your conditions to make it unambiguous.

Comment: @AmigoJack: When in doubt: do that *or* consult the documentation.

Comment: The abbreviation [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM) seems to exist since 1979, but then again I've also encountered bad/sloppy documentations already. I think almost nobody uses the internet as an infinite library of knowledge anymore today, that's why common sense for details also vanishes.